# Utilize multiple executors and workers in Spark job

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark on a standalone mode with below spark-env configuration -

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4g
```

With this I can see 4 workers on my spark UI 8080.

Now One thing is the number of executors on my master URL (4040) is just one, how can I increases this to say 2 per worker node.

Also when I am running a small code from spark its just making use of one executer, do I need to make any config change to ensure multiple executors on multiple workers are used.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set spark.master parameter as local[k], where k is the number of threads you want to utilize. You'd better to write these parameters inside spark-submit command instead of using export.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel processing is based on number of partions of RDD. If your Rdd has multiple partions then it will processed parallelly.

Do some Modification (`repartion`) in your code, it should work.